# Deploy nodejs issue on CF/BlueMix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

When I try to deploy the following repo to CF/BlueMix I got errors for the  "devDependencies":

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
```

If I add webpack to the dep I got error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'postcss-cssnext'
```

and continue for other dev dep....

Which part of the **devDependencies** , does the deploy shouldn't install only the "prod" dependency?

This is the repo: https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter

I run the build locally with `npm run bs` and I put in the manifest.yml the following

```
---
applications:
- name: myapp
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  memory: 512M
  command: npm run start:prod
  services:
    - mong
```

what could be the reason of faliing on devdependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

> Are you pushing to Bluemix with the node_modules folder in your project? If you are, try deleting it entirely and repushing.

Also,

> Just add the line node_modules in your .cfignore file to ignore the node_modules directory. The buildpack will run node install in your cloud foundry container. Also I'd recommend you to do a cf delete  to remove it from cache and then do a cf push  again

**Source**: See the comments from this question: [unable to push node.js cloudant app to bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754291/unable-to-push-node-js-cloudant-app-to-bluemix)

---

**Update**

I think I have reproduced the problem:

```
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.defineProperty.value (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.bundle.js:280:19)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.bundle.js:1930:17)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.defineProperty.value (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.bundle.js:2074:31)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at __webpack_require__ (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.bundle.js:20:30)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at /home/vcap/app/dist/server.bundle.js:40:18
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/server.bundle.js:43:10)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2017-01-01T23:12:14.45+0000 [App/0]      ERR     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

The webpack import issue seems to be with the file `dist/server.bundle.js` which for me was generated by the command `npm run bs`.

The dist folder is getting uploaded to Bluemix and appears to be getting imported when your app starts.

Can you exclude the dist folder in `.cfignore` and build it when your app is uploaded with `cf push`?  I'm not sure if you add multiple commands in manifest.yml, e.g.

```
command: npm <<your_new_build_command>> && npm run start:prod
```

However, it looks as though whatever you do in your new build command (e.g. `npm run bs:prod`) only picks up production dependencies when it creates your dist folder.

If you can't run multiple commands from the manifest.yml, then you may need to change `start:prod` so that it also performs a build step for the production environment.

**Update 2**

You can ask the node buildpack to not cache modules and download them each time you push by using `NODE_MODULES_CACHE: false`, e.g.

```
applications:
- name: ...
  buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
  memory: 512M
  command: ...
  env:
     NODE_MODULES_CACHE: false
```

Comment: No I put it already in the .cf ignore -> node_modules/ , there is option to clear cache without delete ?

Comment: I'm not sure, however, this questions looks like it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006154/how-can-i-avoid-loading-buildpack-components-from-cache-on-bluemix

Comment: and regard the issue which is trying to download the dev dep? any idea direction?  Im stuck...Thanks!

Comment: have you tried setting the `--production` flag or `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack/issues/16

Comment: How can I do it you please give example? I try in the manifest to put also   env:
    NODE_ENV: production which doesnt help...

Comment: Do you have any bluemix instance maybe you can clone the repo and do the steps it taks 3-5 min maybe you will have any direction ...Thanks for the support!

Comment: Hi thanks for effort 1+ , do you mean run the npm run bs & npm run start:prod together ? if so the commands(in the yaml) cannot get two attributes ? (maybe the sequence matter ) ,btw did you able to run it ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more information.  I think you need a new build command that builds `dist` without the devDependencies.

Comment: as workaround I put all the dev dependencies inside the dependency and still its not working, this should solve the issue (as quick workaround ) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132084/discussion-between-chris-snow-and-rayn-d).

Comment: Did you able to run it in your machine ?